# How to add list of options as a response to user in api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to design a simple bot using api.ai. What I want to do is when the user asks a specific question e.g. I want to design a website, I want to return a list of choices. e.g. What kind of website do you want to develop
1) Static
2) Dynamic
3) One Page Design

And once the user clicks on one of these (or he can input a choice number) then I should be able to get his choice, so that I can give further info on the selected choice.

How can I accomplish this in api.ai?

Comment: I'll tell you what I think can be done. Create a webhook for your bot. And allow webhook for slot filling https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook#webhook-for-slot-filling. Now in your webhook, you must configure the rich message response for your options manually and then send it to API.AI

Answer (score 0):

Define a developper entity 'website_kind' (with synonyms if needed):
- static / fixed
- dynamic
- one page design / single page

Define your intent with this entity "How can I design a static website": your developper entity should be recognized (ie @website_kind).

Check the 'required' checkbox for @website_kind and add a prompt when this parameter is not set (ie "What kind of web site would you like to create, static, dynamic or one page").

This should work ;-)

Comment: The OP asked for a bot where simpl clicking on a one of the options would work, for example in facebook messenger you can reply with cards. I know that you can do this with final Response, but we cant currently do this with prompts for required params.